SQLProvider's SaveConfigurationInstances disabling login in ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm migrating an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API to .NET 8.0 and there's a problem with logging in through the front-end. Despite entering the correct credentials, the Web API returns a server 500 error. After debugging a lot, I found out that the problem lies with SQLProvider's SaveConfigurationInstances, because when I enable it, login stops working, but once I comment it out, the login works again.
I tried searching up more about this function but couldn't find much, and I didn't write this codebase, so I have no idea what's what.
Here's the code containing for when the login API call is made:
AccountController:
public AccountController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
    IEmailSender emailSender,
    IConfiguration config,
    IUserService userService,
    IIdentityService identityService,
    ISqlProvider sqlProvider)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _config = config;
    _userService = userService;
    _identityService = identityService;
    _sqlProvider = sqlProvider;
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("~/api/Token")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Token([FromBody] UserModel userParam)
{
    UserModel user = await _userService.AuthenticateAsync(userParam.Username, userParam.Password);
    
    if (user == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });
    }
    else if (user.Id != 0)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Account is inactive or is expired" });
    }
    else
    {
        SessionHistoryModel sessionHist = new SessionHistoryModel();
        sessionHist.Action = "Login";
        sessionHist.HistTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        sessionHist.UserId = _sqlProvider.GetUserId(user.Username.ToString());
        sessionHist.UserName = user.Username;
        sessionHist.Token = user.Token;

        //int sessionHistStatus = _sqlProvider.SaveConfigurationInstances(sessionHist, "SessionHist");
    }

    return Ok(user);
}

This is the SaveConfigurationInstances method:
 public int SaveConfigurationInstances(object item, string tableName)
 {
     try
     {
         List<object> instancesLs = new List<object>();

         IDictionary<string, object> fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();

         IList<PropertyInfo> propertyLs = new List<PropertyInfo>(item.GetType().GetProperties());

         var sql = new StringBuilder();

         sql.Append($"INSERT INTO [{_appDb.Schema}].{tableName}");
         sql.Append($"( ");
         sql.Append(getColumnSql(item, fields, true));
         sql.Append($") ");
         sql.Append($" VALUES (");

         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> field in fields)
         {
             string fieldKeyCompare = field.Key.Substring(0, field.Key.IndexOf("Col"));

             foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyLs)
             {
                 if (fieldKeyCompare.Equals(property.Name))
                 {
                     string lastProp = fields.Keys.Last().Substring(0, fields.Keys.Last().IndexOf("Col"));

                     if (!(property.Name.Equals("Id") || property.Name.Equals("HistId")))
                     {
                         if (lastProp.Equals(property.Name))
                         {
                             if (property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(bool)) || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
                                 if (tableName == "Base_DocLanguage" && lastProp.Equals("Zh"))
                                 {
                                     sql.Append($"N\'{property.GetValue(item)}\')");
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     sql.Append($"\'{property.GetValue(item)}\')");
                                 }
                             else
                             {
                                 sql.Append($"{property.GetValue(item)})");
                             }

                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if (property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(bool)) || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
                                 sql.Append($"\'{property.GetValue(item)}\', ");
                             else
                                 sql.Append($"{property.GetValue(item)} , ");
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         int status = 0;

         using (var connection = _appDb.Connection)
         {
             connection.Open();

             using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection))
             {
                 if (tableName.Equals("Base_Documents"))
                 {
                     status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     string sql2 = "SELECT @@Identity as newBaseDoc_Id from Base_Documents";
                     cmd.CommandText = sql2;
                     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                     cmd.Connection = connection;
                     int docId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                     MergeDocWithOperation(item, docId);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
             }
         }

         return status;
     }
     catch (SqlException sqlEx)
     {
         throw new Exception($"SQL Exception attempting to {nameof(SaveConfigurationInstances)}", sqlEx);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new Exception($"Error attempting to {nameof(SaveConfigurationInstances)} : {ex.Message}");
     }
 }


As you have debugged the codes, please tell us which line throw the error and what's the 500 error's details error messages.

@BrandoZhang further debugging reveals the bug is something related to the date/time conversion as the error thrown is Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
